# Bundle script file not being rendered.

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, resourcebundle

Script file name:

```
jquery.transit.min.js
```

The file is in the Scripts folder,

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui")
       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval")
       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jtransit")
       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.transit*"));
```

In my `View`,

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery","~/bundles/jtransit")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Rendered `HTML`

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

`jquery.transit.min.js` doesn't get rendered. What am I missing?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think it will be because you only have the .min version of your file.

From your output I can see that you are running the debug build of your
site.  I guess as such the bundler is looking for a non-minified file.

If you were to do a Release build, then it would be bundled in OK.

I'd suggest getting a non-minified version of the transit file and 
including that in your Scripts folder.  Failing that, just make a 
copy of the minified version but without the .min in the filename.

Comment: cannot believe that ASP.NET use that trick. No error, just fail silently!!

Comment: Also, if the bundle virtual path contains a dot, it would work during development but not working for published site. bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery.validate").Include("~/../Scripts/jquery.validate.*"));

Comment: This solved my problem. No clues anywhere, it just didn't include the script! I remoev .min and all good

Comment: But why did Microsoft decide to ignore bundling min-files?

Answer (score 17):

Starting in `MVC4`, any minimized version of your JavaScript files or CSS files are **ignored** in Debug mode. As ngm suggests, you need to rename your file from,

```
jquery.transit.min.js
```

to,

```
jquery.transit.js
```

Alternatively, you could modified the `bundles.IgnoreList` to allow minimized files to be rendered, as shown [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/general-discussions/vs2012-rtm-mvc4-kendo-bundle-not-rendering.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

I had to do this in Application_Start:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was attempting to use a script bundle and a style bundle with the same name.

BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom")
    .Include("~/Scripts/custom.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/custom")
    .Include("~/CSS/custom.css"));
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/custom")
```

This doesn't work. The last bundle added in the config survives, and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")` just renders an empty line.

I am using MVC 5.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the above questions resolve your problem maybe you're missing this line

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

from the Global.asax.cs file, if you're getting started with bundling take a look of this site: 
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 0):

In my case Visual Studio 2013 just thought that bundling css files are missing, it showed yellow question mark over the filename in Solution Explorer.

Just double-click all these *supposedly missing* files and Visual Studio will find them, yellow question will mark dismiss and bundling will start working again like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

and make sure you're not using IE 8. Bundling failed for me in that browser but works fine in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: bundles are created at server side, so browser should not make difference