# ASP.NET MVC Script bundle not rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript, scriptbundle

I've included the following line in the `BundleConfig.cs` file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
  "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
```

However when I try to render it among other scripts, it's skipped.

Here is how I render the scripts:

```
@Scripts.Render(
    "~/bundles/jquery",
    "~/bundles/jqueryui",
    "~/bundles/jqueryajax",
    "~/bundles/jquerytree")
```

This is the output HTML, the *jqueryajax* bundle is omitted:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bundle script file not being rendered.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365673/bundle-script-file-not-being-rendered)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe `ScriptBundle` tries to minify the file when `debug="false"` instead of using the existing `.min.js` file. There is a setting in web.config to affect how this works (set **usePreMinifiedFiles** to ***true***):

```
<core enableTracing="false" ...>
     <js defaultMinifier="EdwardsJsMinifier" usePreMinifiedFiles="true">
```

Comment: I just removed the `min` part in the *BundleConfig.cs* file. Thanks.